# Generate standalone eps figures with tex labels substituted

Tags: pdftex, psfrag, pstool

Currently, I am using `pstool` and using `psfragfig` to include figures, which are `eps` format with labels in a separate `tex` file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pstool}

\begin{document}
   \begin{figure}
      \centering
      \psfragfig[width=0.5\textwidth]{./fig1}
      \caption{Fig1 caption}
      \label{fig:1}
   \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

My journal is asking now for figure `eps` files with labels substituted (i.e. no separate `tex` file for figures). One option is, I can compile article with `pdflatex` which generates figures with labels substituted in `pdf` format. I can convert these figures to `eps` format in terminal for example. I tried it however the figures produced as `pdf` are not in same size as the original file. There are a lot of space left around figures.

Is there a easier procedure to substitute labels and save figures as `eps` files?

Answer (score 0):

Though I don't have a direct solution for this, I created a work around which worked fine. First, I compiled the article using `pdflatex` which resulted in figures with substituted labels in `pdf` format. Later, I ran a script to convert `pdf` to `eps`. There are several [options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44736917/high-quality-pdf-to-eps) for this conversion. I tried using `pdftops` option. The following is the automated script to convert `pdf` to `eps` in batch.

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.pdf; do
    echo ${f%%.*}.eps
    pdftops -level3 -eps $f ${f%%.*}.eps
done
```